# invalid literal for int() with base 10: when trying with a value with "," present in it

Tags: python, string, int

```
>>> x='2,33'
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> y=int(x)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    y=int(x)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,33'
>>>
```

I am facing issue when try to convert a value return from another function into int for calculation purpose.
The problem is with "," present in that string, any idea how to remove it.

Comment: Which integer in the string do you want converted into an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve. If you want to keep either 2 or 33 in your example, you can use :

```
>>> y = int(x.split(',')[0])
>>> y
2
>>> type(y)
<type 'int'>
```

If you want both values to be concatenated, you can use :

```
>>> z = int(x.replace(',', ''))
>>> z
233
>>> type(z)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks for help 3kt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the integer part only, you can try stripping the part after the comma, e.g.:

```
int(x[:x.find(',')])
```